# How do I pass an array to a FLUIDTEMPLATE?

Tags: typo3, fluid-layout, fluid

In a fresh Typo3-installation I have a template like this.

```typoscript
page = PAGE
page {

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = fileadmin/default/templates/index.html
        ...

        variables {
            ...

            myPages = CONTENT
            myPages {
                table = pages
                select {
                    pidInList = 76
                    orderBy = sorting
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to iterate over the pages in my fluidtemplate like this:

```html
<f:for each="{myPages}" as="page">
    <f:format.raw>{page.title}</f:format.raw>
</f:for>
```

Unfortunately if I do an 
`<f:debug title="debugger">{myPages}</f:debug>`
it shows that this is an empty string.

How do I pass the result array of my selected content objects to the FLUIDTEMPLATE?

**UPDATE:**

I solved it creating a custom viewhelper, which returns an array of pages for a given parentId. The result is stored in a fluid variable.

```php
class Tx_Custom_ViewHelpers_Pages_GetViewHelper extends Tx_Fluid_Core_ViewHelper_AbstractViewHelper {

    /**
     * Gets subpages for a given page.
     *
     * @param int $parentId ID of the parentpage.
     * @param string $target Target Variable
     */
    public function render($parentId, $target='content') {
        $rows = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('*', 'pages', 'pid=' . $parentId);
        if ($this->templateVariableContainer->exists($target) === TRUE) {
            $this->templateVariableContainer->remove($target);
        }
        $this->templateVariableContainer->add($target, $rows);
    }

}
```

Usage in the template:

```html
{namespace cn=Tx_Custom_ViewHelpers}

<cn:pages.get parentId="{parentId}" target="pages"/>
<f:for each="{pages}" as="p">
    page: {p.title}
</f:for>
```

Remaining typoscript:

```typoscript
page = PAGE
page {

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10{
        file = fileadmin/default/templates/index.html
        layoutRootPath = fileadmin/default/templates/layouts/
        partialRootPath = fileadmin/default/templates/partials/

        variables {
            content < styles.content.get
            parentId = TEXT
            parentId.value = 76
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A CONTENT object is not an array... so Benjamin's comment to the answer applies.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But you should write it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since TYPO3 6.1 you can assign a array to a settings variable:

```
lib.globalSettings { # Access to constants works, too.
  foo = value
}

page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  file = fileadmin/templates/MyTemplate.html
  settings < lib.globalSettings
}
```

http://jweiland.net/typo3/versionen-und-updates/version-61.html#c4300
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/23853

Comment: Unfortunately the last comment regarding the issue is right. The initial problem is not addressed at all. see: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/23853#note-9 
It is still not possible to pass the result of `myPages` as an array to the template.

Comment: Maybe you could use the fedext vhs record-view-helper:
https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Resource/RecordViewHelper.html
I did not see a sort-option, maybe you have to add that yourself.
As an alternative you can of course also write your own viewhelper..

Comment: Thank for the direction you put me, @Benjamin. I actually solved it by writing my own viewhelpers. This also allows me to get rid of the contentobject in typoscript completely.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [DataProcessing](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html?highlight=dataprocessing#dataprocessing).

```
page {
    10 {
        dataProcessing {
            999 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            999 {
                table = pages
                pidInList = 76
                where = deleted=0 AND hidden=0
                orderBy = sorting
                markers.uid.field = uid
                as = myPages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access an array of all found records with your self defined variable myPages within fluid.
To see the contents of the hole array use

```
<f:debug title="debugger">{myPages}</f:debug>
```

Comment: Works and tested in typo3 9.5